# A required privilege is not held by the client. error in vb project

Tags: vb.net, filestream, ioexception, save-image

my program wrote in vb.net. in run time,give me "IO Exception was caught"

[image]

please help me.

Comment: i test all Drives that have in my computer, but didn't work!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the file that you are trying to create with the `FileStream` already exists. Use `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` to solve your problem or delete the file first.

[FileStream creation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyhc0kft%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).